# How to Handle XY Problems for Off-Topic X

Tags: discussion, xy-problem

**Preface**: There are a large suite of questions on meta about handling XY problems; I have looked at this, but never found any that met my criteria.  [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322991/what-should-i-do-when-the-op-asks-the-wrong-question) talks about handling XY Problem questions, but not whether or not the validity of X has any bearing on StackOverflow.  [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349383/how-to-respond-to-xy-problem-when-y-is-an-already-answered-duplicate-question) one talks about duplicate Y, but no bearing on X.  Possible I missed it in the sea of questions; I just wanted to outline that at least *some* due diligence was done here.

---

**Question**: I was giving an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48773083/1601729) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771831/can-static-global-variables-be-optimised-to-be-in-the-stack/48773083).  That question, in a vacuum, I believe to be on-topic (regardless of if it is good or not).

However, the question is asking about the particular solution, instead of the problem that is being experienced ([XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).  But the problem at hand (IE: "my software engineers aren't writing proper software; how do I deal with this") would likely be considered both off-topic and primarily opinion-based.

Should this classification of question (XY Problems where the X would be flag-able) be considered acceptable (regardless of +1/-1), or should this be flagged as the root problem would likely get flagged?  It seems odd that the *seemingly correct* way to ask for help about an off-topic question would be to contrive a bad solution which is on-topic, and then ask about that solution (not that I think that's what the asker did here).

Comment: Generally it's enough to just say that the problem is Y (and why, and why a solution to X wouldn't be helpful), without going into a detailed answer on Y, given that Y is off topic.

Comment: That's pretty atrocious Q+A.  You can't always believe the back-story, that he picked an answer that is utterly useless to him ought to be a hint.  When it smells fishy like that then your effort tends to be expended better elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see that question as off-topic, even from the point of view you suggest. The remark of the OP about their software engineers is merely an ancillary footnote, which provides a little extra context to the question. To put it in a different way, if rather than...

> You must be asking yourself, why then don't just I use a local variable instead. You are correct to ask but this a common mistake new C developers at my work do and I wanted to know [...]

... the OP had said...

> You must be asking yourself, why then don't just I use a local variable instead. You are correct to ask but I'm just curious about whether [...]

... the appropriateness of the question being here wouldn't have come into question. The OP's motives for asking the question, in general, are of secondary importance next to the question itself.

Comment: For the record, I also believe the question to be on-topic in vacuum (as I mentioned), but either of your wordings above would still have me thinking that the author is asking an XY problem.  The latter just leaves me mystified as to what the X is (which I would then likely probe about).

Comment: The result is (in either case) we have a question which is technically on topic, but is really opening up discussion for off-topic content to give the *right* answer (as this particular question outlines).

Comment: @Ironcache Detecting a XY problem means that, if X is on-topic, you can choose to address it instead of Y and possibly end up with a more useful answer. If X is off-topic, you can't do much about it, other than perhaps leaving a comment addressing it. That alone doesn't make Y off-topic though. As for "opening up discussion for off-topic content", such an opportunity can always be rejected as long as the question isn't essentially about off-topic matters.